# What questions should I be asking in order to debug this I2C?

Tags: stm32, embedded, rust

I'm currently working on a bare metal embedded rust project and I'm trying to get the I2C peripheral on the STM32 Nucleo board to work. I've managed to start the peripheral and even get the master to send the address of the slave (was giving me issues before). However, when I try to initialize the LCD, which requires me to restart the peripheral a few times. The sb bit won't set all of a sudden and the code gets hung up at the while loop that checks the start condition. I'm a novice at this and I don't even know which questions to ask at this point. I have no idea why the start function would work in main but not when called from another function.

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

pub mod stm32_lib;

extern crate alloc;

use alloc::vec::Vec;
use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use stm32_lib::rcc;
use stm32f4::stm32f446;

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: emballoc::Allocator<4096> = emballoc::Allocator::new();

const SLAVE_ADDRESS: u8 = 0x4e;

fn i2c_config(
    rcc: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::RCC,
    gpio: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::GPIOB,
    i2c: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::I2C1,
) {
    //Enable 12c and gpio clocks
    rcc.apb1enr.write(|w| w.i2c1en().set_bit());
    rcc.ahb1enr.write(|w| w.gpioben().set_bit());

    //configure gpio pins

    gpio.moder.write(|w| w.moder8().bits(0b10)); // place pin PB8 and PB9 in alternate fucntion mode
    gpio.moder.modify(|_r, w| w.moder9().bits(0b10));

    gpio.otyper.modify(|_r, w| w.ot8().set_bit()); // enabling open drain mode for pin PB8 and PB9
    gpio.otyper.modify(|_r, w| w.ot9().set_bit());

    gpio.ospeedr.modify(|_r, w| w.ospeedr8().bits(0b11)); // setting the pins PB8 and PB9 to high speed (fastest)
    gpio.ospeedr.modify(|_r, w| w.ospeedr9().bits(0b11));

    gpio.pupdr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.pupdr8().bits(0b01) }); //setting the pull up resistors for pinis PB8 and PB9
    gpio.pupdr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.pupdr9().bits(0b01) });

    gpio.afrh.modify(|_r, w| w.afrh8().bits(0b0100)); //setting the alternate mode to i2c for pins PB8 and PB9
    gpio.afrh.modify(|_r, w| w.afrh9().bits(0b0100));

    i2c.cr1.write(|w| w.swrst().set_bit()); // put i2c in the reset state
    i2c.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.swrst().clear_bit()); //take i2c out of reset state

    // Program the peripheral input clock in I2c_cr2 register in order to generate correct timings
    i2c.cr2.write(|w| unsafe { w.freq().bits(0b101101) }); //setting periphercal input clock fequency to 45mhz (current max value of APB)
    i2c.cr2.modify(|_r, w| w.itevten().enabled()); //enable even interrupts

    //configure the clock control registers
    i2c.ccr.write(|w| w.f_s().standard());
    i2c.ccr.modify(|_r, w| w.duty().duty2_1());
    i2c.ccr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.ccr().bits(0b11100001) }); //setting crr to 225 (calculated see manual)
    i2c.trise.modify(|_r, w| w.trise().bits(0b101110)); // configure the rise time register (calculated see manual)
    i2c.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.pe().set_bit()); // Enable the peripheral in i2c_cr1 register
}
fn timer_config(rcc: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::RCC, timer: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::TIM11) {
    //Enable Timer clock
    rcc.apb2enr.modify(|_r, w| w.tim11en().set_bit());
    //initialize timer for delay
    // Set the prescaler and the ARR
    timer.psc.modify(|_r, w| w.psc().bits(0b0000000010110011)); //180MHz/180 = 1MHz ~ 1us, prescalar set to 179, ie. 179+1 = 180;
    timer.arr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.arr().bits(0xffff) });

    //Enable the Timer, and wait for the update Flag to set
    timer.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.cen().set_bit());
    timer.sr.read().uif().bit();
    while !timer.sr.read().uif().bit() {}
}

pub fn i2c_start(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    //send the Start condition
    while i2c.sr2.read().busy().bit_is_set() {}
    i2c.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.start().set_bit()); // setting the start bit

    while !i2c.sr1.read().sb().bit_is_set() { // waiting for the start condition
    }
}

pub fn i2c_stop(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    i2c.cr1.write(|w| w.stop().set_bit());
}

fn i2c_address(address: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    //send the slave address to the DR register
    i2c.dr.write(|w| w.dr().bits(address));
    while !i2c.sr1.read().addr().is_match() {}
    let _temp = i2c.sr1.read(); //reading sr1 and sr2 to clear the addr bit
    let _temp2 = i2c.sr2.read();
}

fn i2c_write(data: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    //wait for the TXE bit 7 in cr1 to set. This indicates that the DR is empty
    while !i2c.sr1.read().tx_e().is_empty() {}
    //load the data in the data register
    i2c.dr.write(|w| w.dr().bits(data));
    //wait for data transfer to finish
    while !i2c.sr1.read().btf().is_finished() {}
}

//LCD functions

fn lcd_write(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, address: u8, data: Vec<u8>, size: usize) {
    i2c_start(i2c);
    i2c_address(address, i2c);
    for i in 0..size {
        i2c_write(data[i], i2c);
    }
    i2c_stop(i2c);
}

fn lcd_write_str(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, input: &str) {
    //convert the string to a vector of bytes
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = input.bytes().collect();
    for &byte in &bytes {
        lcd_send_data(byte, i2c);
    }
}

fn lcd_send_cmd(cmd: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    let data_u: u8;
    let data_l: u8;
    let temp: u8;
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    data_u = cmd & 0xf0;
    temp = cmd << 4;
    data_l = temp & 0xf0;
    data.push(data_u | 0x0c); //en = 1 & rs = 0
    data.insert(1, data_u | 0x08); //en = 0 & rs = 0
    data.insert(2, data_l | 0x0c); //en = 1 & rs = 0
    data.insert(3, data_l | 0x08); //en = 0 & rs = 0
    lcd_write(i2c, SLAVE_ADDRESS, data, 4);
}

fn lcd_send_data(data: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    let data_u: u8;
    let data_l: u8;
    let temp: u8;
    let mut data_t: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    data_u = data & 0xf0;
    temp = data << 4;
    data_l = temp & 0xf0;
    data_t.push(data_u | 0x0c); //en = 1 & rs = 1
    data_t.insert(1, data_u | 0x08); //en = 0 & rs = 1
    data_t.insert(2, data_l | 0x0c); //en = 1 & rs = 1
    data_t.insert(3, data_l | 0x08); //en = 1 & rs = 1
    lcd_write(i2c, SLAVE_ADDRESS, data_t, 4);
}

fn lcd_clear(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    lcd_send_cmd(0x80, i2c);
    for _ in 0..70 {
        lcd_send_data(' ' as u8, i2c);
    }
}

fn lcd_put_cur(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, row: u8, mut col: u8) {
    match row {
        0 => col |= 0x80,
        1 => col |= 0xc0,
        _ => {}
    }
    lcd_send_cmd(col, i2c)
}

fn lcd_init(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, timer: &mut stm32f446::TIM11) {
    // 4 bit initialisation
    rcc::delay_ms(50, timer); //wait for >40ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x30, i2c);
    rcc::delay_ms(5, timer); //wait for >4.1ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x30, i2c);
    rcc::delay_us(150, timer); //wait for >100ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x30, i2c);
    rcc::delay_ms(10, timer); //wait for >4.1ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x20, i2c); //4bit mode
    rcc::delay_ms(10, timer);

    //display initialisation
    lcd_send_cmd(0x28, i2c); // function set ---> DL=0 (4 bit mode), N = 1 (2 line display) F = 0 (5*8 characters)
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x08, i2c); // Display on/off control --> D=0, C=0, B=0 ---> display off
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x01, i2c); // clear display
    rcc::delay_ms(2, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x06, i2c); // Entry mode set --> I/D = 1 (increment cursor) & S = 0 (no shift)
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x0C, i2c); // Display on/off control --> D=1, C and B = 0. (Cursor and blink last two bits)
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
}

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let peripherals = stm32f446::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut rcc = peripherals.RCC;
    let mut timer = peripherals.TIM11; //used for the delay
    let mut flash = peripherals.FLASH;
    let mut gpio = peripherals.GPIOB; //general purpose pin normally used as output.
    let mut pwr = peripherals.PWR;
    let mut i2c = peripherals.I2C1;

    rcc::initialize_clock(&mut rcc, &mut pwr, &mut flash);
    timer_config(&mut rcc, &mut timer);
    i2c_config(&mut rcc, &mut gpio, &mut i2c);
    lcd_init(&mut i2c, &mut timer);
    lcd_put_cur(&mut i2c, 0, 0);
    lcd_write_str(&mut i2c, "hello");

    loop {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not describing what the system is alike and what the code is supposed to do. Perhaps the code can be compared to a working code to find out what the issue is. But do we have to assume which display you have and how it communicates over I2C? Looking at the code, you might have a HD44780 compatible display, used in 4-bit parallel bus mode, over a PCF8574 I2C IO expander, which Arduino folks call an I2C backpack for the LCD. You need to find out if the problem is using the I2C bus, or using the IO expander over I2C, or using the LCD over expander. Do you have pull-ups on I2C? What I2C speed?

Comment: Also what tools you have to debug this? Can you single-step code in a debugging environment? Do you have a multimeter, logic anayzer, or oscilloscope for debugging? Do you have schematics and PCB layout to see any design flaws in the hardware? Can you try running proven-to-work C code to test if the problem is in code or hardware?

Comment: I found I2C of the STM32 to be one of the worst peripherals they have. Especially the earlier implementations. I had interrupts go off without any bit being set to identify the cause of it. So for a first implementation, I'd avoid interrupts and use polling. It's a bit of a hassle because the ST library contains code for different modes, but if you understand C code, it's a good reference to see how stuff is implemented there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Justme I definitely left off alot of imformation now that I think about it. Your assumptions were spot on tho, I am using HD44780 compatible display, lcd1602 with the PCF8574 I2c io expander. I do have 10k resistors for pull ups on the SDA and SCL lines, however I'm not sure about the speed. I configured the rise time and high time by following a tutorial but I'll make sure to understand the speed of the peripheral now. 

I was debugging using Vscode to step through the code using Probe-rs toolkit. I do have a multimeter and I used the oscilloscope to help debug the address issue.

Comment: @Justme Your response really gave me an idea though. I was so adamant to get it to work using embedded rust that it never occurred to me to test to ensure that the hardware was ok with proven C code. I will try that out tomorrow depending on how work goes. Thanks for this insight.

Comment: @Justme Hi again, I downloaded the same code in C that I had tried to port over to rust from controllers tech github repo. The I2c works fine in C but now that makes it even stranger that the rust equivalent is not working... I dont know what to think when it comes to these errors im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to 4-bit mode. It doesn't like being put in 4-bit mode when it is already in 4-bit mode. Unfortunately, unless it is a cold-start, there is no way to know what mode it is in.

During initialization, the recommended procedure is to put it in 8-bit mode twice, then put it in 4-bit mode. Don't mess with the 4/8 bit modes after that.

Comment: You are right, the initialisaztion sequence is not entirely correct. It also is not correct going into 4-bit mode the first time. But it would not affect the I2C bus not working and thus prevent MCU from sending start bit properly.

Comment: @Mattman944 As justme pointed out, I would have no problem looking down this path if the I2c was working fine. But its not even passing the first write to the lcd for me to think the initialization is the source of the problem. However, this is interesting to know and I will definitely modify the initialization as soon as I get the I2c to work properly. Thanks alot for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I was of the assumption that I needed to restart the peripheral after sending each command but turns out I didnt. I also didnt need to stop the i2c communication protocol until I was actually done transmitting. So I could initialize and send data all without restarting the peripheral. Chatgpt helped me to realize where my understanding was waning and provided useful suggestions. This is the final code (This code is a port of the c code written by controllers tech in rust):

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

pub mod stm32_lib;

use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use stm32_lib::rcc;
use stm32f4::stm32f446;

const SLAVE_ADDRESS: u8 = 0x4e;

fn i2c_config(
    rcc: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::RCC,
    gpio: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::GPIOB,
    i2c: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::I2C1,
) {
    //Enable 12c and gpio clocks
    rcc.apb1enr.write(|w| w.i2c1en().set_bit());
    rcc.ahb1enr.write(|w| w.gpioben().set_bit());

    //configure gpio pins

    gpio.moder.write(|w| w.moder8().bits(0b10)); // place pin PB8 and PB9 in alternate fucntion mode
    gpio.moder.modify(|_r, w| w.moder9().bits(0b10));

    gpio.otyper.modify(|_r, w| w.ot8().set_bit()); // enabling open drain mode for pin PB8 and PB9
    gpio.otyper.modify(|_r, w| w.ot9().set_bit());

    gpio.ospeedr.modify(|_r, w| w.ospeedr8().bits(0b11)); // setting the pins PB8 and PB9 to high speed (fastest)
    gpio.ospeedr.modify(|_r, w| w.ospeedr9().bits(0b11));

    gpio.pupdr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.pupdr8().bits(0b01) }); //setting the pull up resistors for pinis PB8 and PB9
    gpio.pupdr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.pupdr9().bits(0b01) });

    gpio.afrh.modify(|_r, w| w.afrh8().bits(0b0100)); //setting the alternate mode to i2c for pins PB8 and PB9
    gpio.afrh.modify(|_r, w| w.afrh9().bits(0b0100));

    i2c.cr1.write(|w| w.swrst().set_bit()); // put i2c in the reset state
    i2c.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.swrst().clear_bit()); //take i2c out of reset state

    // Program the peripheral input clock in I2c_cr2 register in order to generate correct timings
    i2c.cr2.write(|w| unsafe { w.freq().bits(0b101101) }); //setting periphercal input clock fequency to 45mhz (current max value of APB)
    i2c.cr2.modify(|_r, w| w.itevten().enabled()); //enable even interrupts

    //configure the clock control registers
    i2c.ccr.write(|w| w.f_s().standard());
    i2c.ccr.modify(|_r, w| w.duty().duty2_1());
    i2c.ccr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.ccr().bits(0b11100001) }); //setting crr to 225 (calculated see manual)
    i2c.trise.modify(|_r, w| w.trise().bits(0b101110)); // configure the rise time register (calculated see manual)
    i2c.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.pe().set_bit()); // Enable the peripheral in i2c_cr1 register
}

fn timer_config(rcc: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::RCC, timer: &mut stm32f4::stm32f446::TIM11) {
    //Enable Timer clock
    rcc.apb2enr.modify(|_r, w| w.tim11en().set_bit());
    //initialize timer for delay
    // Set the prescaler and the ARR
    timer.psc.modify(|_r, w| w.psc().bits(0b0000000010110011)); //180MHz/180 = 1MHz ~ 1us, prescalar set to 179, ie. 179+1 = 180;
    timer.arr.modify(|_r, w| unsafe { w.arr().bits(0xffff) });

    //Enable the Timer, and wait for the update Flag to set
    timer.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.cen().set_bit());
    timer.sr.read().uif().bit();
    while !timer.sr.read().uif().bit() {}
}

pub fn i2c_start(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    //send the Start condition
    while i2c.sr2.read().busy().bit_is_set() {}
    i2c.cr1.modify(|_r, w| w.start().set_bit()); // setting the start bit

    while !i2c.sr1.read().sb().bit_is_set() { // waiting for the start condition
    }
}

pub fn i2c_stop(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    i2c.cr1.write(|w| w.stop().set_bit());
}

fn i2c_address(address: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    //send the slave address to the DR register
    i2c.dr.write(|w| w.dr().bits(address));
    while !i2c.sr1.read().addr().is_match() {}
    let _temp = i2c.sr1.read(); //reading sr1 and sr2 to clear the addr bit
    let _temp2 = i2c.sr2.read();
}

fn i2c_write(data: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    //wait for the TXE bit 7 in cr1 to set. This indicates that the DR is empty
    while !i2c.sr1.read().tx_e().is_empty() {}
    //load the data in the data register
    i2c.dr.write(|w| w.dr().bits(data));
    //wait for data transfer to finish
    while !i2c.sr1.read().btf().is_finished() {}
}

//LCD functions

fn lcd_write(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, data: &[u8; 4]) {
    for i in 0..4 {
        i2c_write(data[i], i2c);
    }
}

fn lcd_write_str(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, input: &str) {
    for byte in input.bytes() {
        lcd_send_data(byte, i2c);
    }
}

fn lcd_send_cmd(cmd: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    let data_u: u8;
    let data_l: u8;
    let temp: u8;
    data_u = cmd & 0xf0;
    temp = cmd << 4;
    data_l = temp & 0xf0;
    let data: [u8; 4] = [
        data_u | 0x0C, // en=1, rs=0
        data_u | 0x08, // en=0, rs=0
        data_l | 0x0C, // en=1, rs=0
        data_l | 0x08, // en=0, rs=0
    ];
    lcd_write(i2c, &data);
}

fn lcd_send_data(data: u8, i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    let data_u: u8;
    let data_l: u8;
    let temp: u8;
    data_u = data & 0xf0;
    temp = data << 4;
    data_l = temp & 0xf0;
    let data_t: [u8; 4] = [
        data_u | 0x0D, // en=1, rs=0
        data_u | 0x09, // en=0, rs=0
        data_l | 0x0D, // en=1, rs=0
        data_l | 0x09, // en=0, rs=0
    ];
    lcd_write(i2c, &data_t);
}

fn lcd_clear(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1) {
    lcd_send_cmd(0x80, i2c);
    for _ in 0..70 {
        lcd_send_data(' ' as u8, i2c);
    }
}

fn lcd_put_cur(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, row: u8, mut col: u8) {
    match row {
        0 => col |= 0x80,
        1 => col |= 0xc0,
        _ => {}
    }
    lcd_send_cmd(col, i2c)
}

fn lcd_init(i2c: &mut stm32f446::I2C1, timer: &mut stm32f446::TIM11) {
    // 4 bit initialisation
    rcc::delay_ms(50, timer); //wait for >40ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x30, i2c);
    rcc::delay_ms(5, timer); //wait for >4.1ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x30, i2c);
    rcc::delay_us(150, timer); //wait for >100ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x30, i2c);
    rcc::delay_ms(10, timer); //wait for >4.1ms
    lcd_send_cmd(0x20, i2c); //4bit mode
    rcc::delay_ms(10, timer);

    //display initialisation
    lcd_send_cmd(0x28, i2c); // function set ---> DL=0 (4 bit mode), N = 1 (2 line display) F = 0 (5*8 characters)
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x08, i2c); // Display on/off control --> D=0, C=0, B=0 ---> display off
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x01, i2c); // clear display
    rcc::delay_ms(2, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x06, i2c); // Entry mode set --> I/D = 1 (increment cursor) & S = 0 (no shift)
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
    lcd_send_cmd(0x0C, i2c); // Display on/off control --> D=1, C and B = 0. (Cursor and blink last two bits)
    rcc::delay_ms(1, timer);
}

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let peripherals = stm32f446::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut rcc = peripherals.RCC;
    let mut timer = peripherals.TIM11; //used for the delay
    let mut flash = peripherals.FLASH;
    let mut gpio = peripherals.GPIOB; //general purpose pin normally used as output.
    let mut pwr = peripherals.PWR;
    let mut i2c = peripherals.I2C1;

    rcc::initialize_clock(&mut rcc, &mut pwr, &mut flash);
    timer_config(&mut rcc, &mut timer);
    i2c_config(&mut rcc, &mut gpio, &mut i2c);
    i2c_start(&mut i2c);
    i2c_address(SLAVE_ADDRESS, &mut i2c);
    lcd_init(&mut i2c, &mut timer);
    lcd_put_cur(&mut i2c, 0, 0);
    lcd_write_str(&mut i2c, "Hello Worldk");
    i2c_stop(&mut i2c);

    loop {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```